# Book about teens with powers

Tags: story-identification, novel

These teens have powers and each book is a different kid's story.

The cover is a different color according to the story. There's the face of the kid on the cover.

There's a girl in one of the books that can read minds or something like that.  This man claiming to be her father comes into her life and asks her to help with his gambling. She agrees and helps the man cheat by reading the other players' minds. He pays her in gifts. The girl's friend suspects something is up, so she goes behind the girls back and gets a DNA test to see if it's actually the girl's father and it's not. And that's when the book ends.

Another book is about this guy and if I recall correctly, he can talk to the dead. And by the end of somewhere In the book he helps a suffering family find a winning lotto ticket that a dead relative left behind when they died. And the ticket was under the porch or a step.

Comment: Sorry, I need to ask: Why didn't the girl just read her "Dad's" mind to see if he was really her father?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is called *Gifted*, it's a series. There are 6 books.
[image]

Comment: Aside from the cover/s, what else about these stories match the description?